# how to know if the LIPO battery I have is compatible with the motors and motor driver I have

Tags: battery

I am building a robot and I have a concern. Will it properly connect a 11.1V 30C 4500mAh to this motor driver :
https://www.pololu.com/product/708

thanks in advance ..

Comment: i have no idea what you are asking here `and depends on what I can judge ?` ... i think that the translation from your language did not work correctly

Comment: connecting this motor driver with a LIPO battery matching the above specification , is it a proper connection in other words am I gonna damage my motor driver ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check your driver specifications and get the battery accordingly.

The *driver* specs you need to check:

**Voltage Rating**

- The voltage range that the motor is designed to operate. Within the range you can select a voltage value that suits your needs best.

**No Load Current**

- The current drawn by the motor when its running free with nothing connected to the shaft. (For small motors, when you hold them in the hand and the shaft is not yet connect to the wheels, propellers etc).This indicates the minimum current your power supply must be able to provide in order for the motor to turn.

**Stall Current**

- When you increase the load on the motor shaft, at some point of time, the motor shaft will stop turning. This is called motor stall. The current drawn by the motor in this state is called the stall current. This is also the maximum current that will be needed by the motor.

**Power**

- This is generally given in “Watts”. In a large number of cases, I have seen that the watt rating is not specified. That should not be a problem as long as we have the voltage and current ratings.

**Torque**

- This is an indicator of how much weight the motor can lift at a given distance. If the rating is 1Kgcm, it means, that 1 cm from the shaft, you can attach a maximum of 1Kg load and the motor can lift it.

The *battery* specs you need to check:

**Voltage Rating**

- The voltage a new battery is expected to deliver

**Current/Capacity Rating**

- The maximum amount of current a battery can deliver in one hour. This is a very confusing specification. Suppose a battery is rated at 1500mAh. That means, it can deliver 1500mA in one hour.

**Discharge Rate**

- This indicates what is the maximum current a battery can deliver. A 1C rating means, the battery can discharge at Capacity x 1.

*To answer your question*, when you compare these spec values for your driver and battery, if they're in each other's range, you can use your battery with the motor driver.